# Email template override - not showing changes

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I wont to add new table column inside of my **"sales_email_order_items"** template file. I have found it in

```
/app/design/frontend/Emthemes/everything/default/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items.phtml
```

But whatever I change in code it does not reflected to the email template.

I tried to rename **pub/ cache**, **view_preprocessed**, **generation**, **page_cache**.

Also I run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**, but nothing. Email stands as it was.

What step am I missing?

Comment: can you try with below file 
`/app/design/frontend/Emthemes/everything/default/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml`

Comment: That actually worked. If you can post it I will marked it as answered, so you can get your points :)

Comment: :( Bad Luck but happy to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another file that actually needed to be change as Dhaval user pointed out in the comment:

```
/app/design/frontend/Emthemes/everything/default/Magento_Sal‌​es/templates/email/i‌​tems.phtml
```